# When passing a pointer as an argument is the address & symbol not required / automatically added by compiler?

Tags: c, function, pointers

In the below code, a *Pointer is passed to a function.

The address & symbol is omitted.

The functions can still modify the value in the passed pointer.

Does the compiler auto-add the &?

```
char * input();

void get_command() {
    char * command_pointer = input();
    char * second = second_arg(command_pointer); //second needs to be before first
    char * first = first_arg(command_pointer);   //becuase first adds a /0 
    choose(first, second);
    free(command_pointer);   
}

char * first_arg(char * arg) {  
    char * j = strchr(arg, '-');
    if(j==NULL) {
        return arg;
    }
    *j = '\0';
    return arg;
}

char * second_arg(char * arg) {  
    char * j = strchr(arg, '-');
    if( j==NULL  ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return ++j; 
}
```

Comment: Your `command_pointer` is *already* a `char*` pointer and that's what the `second_arg` function takes as its parameter. The function can modify the data *pointed to* but it can't modify the actual pointer (i.e. change the address that that holds in the calling module).

Comment: Make sure to keep straight the distinction between the value of a pointer, and the value of the data that it points to.  `second_arg` can modify the data that `command_pointer` points to; that's what a pointer is for.  But it cannot modify the pointer `command_pointer` itself, because that was passed by value.

Comment: And in that same vein, do not construe the data to which a pointer points as being "in" the pointer.  They are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the compiler auto-add the &?

No. `&` gets the address of a variable, and the address of `command_pointer` isn't passed. Only its value (the address of the buffer) is passed.

> The functions can still modify the value in the passed pointer.

No, they can't. They can't modify (the value of) the pointer. They can only modify that to which the pointer points.

---

`first_arg` and `second_arg` can't change `command_pointer` (the variable in `get_command`) because they don't know anything about it and they don't have a pointer to it.

e.g. `arg = NULL;` would have no effect on `command_pointer`.

However, they can modify the data to which `command_pointer` points (the `char`s), because they have a copy of the same pointer.

e.g. `*arg = 0` (aka `arg[0] = 0;`) would effect `*command_pointer` (aka `command_pointer[0]`).

---

Let's illustrate some of the variables of `get_command` and `first_arg`.

```
input()'s rv         Buffer allocated by input
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---
| 0x1000 -------+--->|   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
+----------+    |    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---
                |                      ^
command_pointer |                      |
+----------+    |                      |
| 0x1000 -------+                      |
+----------+    |                      |
                |                      |
arg             |    j                 |
+----------+    |    +----------+      |
| 0x1000 -------+    | 0x1004 ---------+
+----------+         +----------+
```

- `input()` returns an address to a bufer it allocated (`0x1000` in the diagram).
- The value returned by `input()` is copied into `command_pointer`.
- The value of `command_pointer` is copied into `arg`.
- A value based on `arg` is stored in `j`.
- `get_command` can modify `command_pointer` and the buffer.
- `first_arg` can modify `arg`, `j` and the buffer, but not `command_pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

The value is changed only if you use the * on the pointer. if you will not the value will not change, the address will change. Consider these functions:

```
char * first_arg(char * arg) {  
    arg = 'a';
    // some other code //
}

char * second_arg(char * arg) {  
    *arg = 'c';
    // some other code //
}
```

the first function will change the **address** that arg is pointing at. This function can be dangerous because we don't now what is stored in the address 'a'. This function may change the behavior of otter scopes in an unexpected way. but it will not change the value that arg is pointing at. (except of the scenario that you hardcode the exact address of arg)

the second function will change the **value** in the address arg is pointing at. This is the well defined behavior that we are looking for. This will only change the value of the memory arg is pointing at.